# Vuejs app not rendering in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2

I'm trying to run an example Vuejs app in a chrome extension, as a new tab (i.e. when you open a new tab, the Vuejs app should render). When I run the app from the `dist/` folder using `simplehttpserver dist/` it works just fine as expected, however, when I `Load Unpacked` the dist folder as a Chrome Extension and try opening a new tab, the Vuejs app does not render.

I'm running `npm run build` to build the app and then adding the `manifest.json` and `background.js` files into the `dist/` folder.

One thing I see in the element inspector on the chrome extension version is that the `<div id="app"></div>` for some reason is not included in the DOM, even though it is in the `index.html` file after the build is done.

**Note:** the Vuejs app I'm trying to use as a chrome extension is the default example app `vue init webpack .` creates.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Vuejs test extension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",

  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "chrome://newtab"})
}));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test vuejs app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is in the inspector, maybe some missing files or something not loading?

Comment: is that the html from the dist folder?

Comment: While I didn't use vue with extensions, I remember reading [this article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/08/vue-js-chrome-extension/), about rendering quirks. This part __Unfortunately the template compiler relies on eval functions to perform this compilation task, and these are not allowed under the CSP.__

Comment: Your html doesn't load any scripts. Note that an extension page is a static file which must contain all the resources explicitly mentioned as it's not served by node.js etc.

Comment: Also, I see many answers when googling the question title, including boilerplate templates to use as a base for an extension.

Comment: See the following qestion for how to use Vue and even Vuetify without build tools:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77557516/8583692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a easy and quick fix.

The whole issue, as many have pointed out, is with vue rendering templates in runtime. To do so, it uses the `eval()` function which is by default not allowed by chrome for it's extensions for security reasons.

You can bypass this by adding the following line in your `manifest.json`:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`

This is obviously not recommended as your extension will be prone to cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.

Instead, you can rely on vue rendering the templates in compile time. That way it no longer needs to run `eval()` on your templates.

The easiest way to render templates on compile time is to set the `Vue build` to `runtime` when creating your project with `vue init webpack`.

This forces Vue to use pre-compiled templates according to this article: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/08/vue-js-chrome-extension/

... which is exactly what we need to not use the `eval()` function.

Comment: on Dev mode, Hot-Module-Reload is activated, that's why you need to use `unsafe-eval`, however in production you don't need this.

I created this for the ease of starting project with Vue and Chrome extension
https://github.com/superoo7/vue-cli-plugin-chrome-ext , it has 2 different config for production and development

Comment: thanks sir ! I add it in manifest.json , and it don't work at first . But after I force restart Chrome Extension , it works very well !

Comment: @johnsonlai thank you , you pointed the true reason of this console error .

Answer (score 1):

To create the chrome-extension using Vuejs you can use [this](https://github.com/Kocal/vue-web-extension) boilerplate.
Make sure you have installed the vue-cli if it's not installed you can install it by using `npm install -g @vue/cli.

After installing the vue-cli run this cmd: `vue init kocal/vue-web-extension my-extension`. It will download and install the vuejs boilerplate template for chrome-extension to your current directory. Then you can move to the newly created directory and install the dependencies using the command `npm install`.

Now you have completely setup the vuejs app for your chrome-extension but it will open as popup window to make it visible in new tab it will require some modification as I given below.

1. First go to the `src/manifest.json` file and remove `"default_popup": "popup/popup.html"` from `"browser_action"`
2. Then go to the `src/background.js` file and delete all given code and replace it with the code given below.

   ```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
       chrome.tabs.create(
           {
               url: chrome.extension.getURL('./popup/popup.html'),
           },
           function (tab) { }
       );
   });
   ```
3. Now run run `npm run build` and it will generate the dist folder which you can use as your extension folder. That you can open in chrome by doing using `Load unpacked` option in chrome extensions menu.

And you are done you can see the vuejs app running in new tab window by clicking on the extension icon.

Let me know if it worked or not if not worked then please lemem know whats the problem you are facing.

Comment: Gotcha. It seems to work however I see it relies on adding the `unsafe-eval` in the extension manifest:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`

Is there a way to avoid this and still make the vuejs app render?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I can see in a webpack.config.js file that it's only adding  `unsafe-eval` to `manifest.json` in development mode. If you do `npm run build` and check the manifest file inside dist folder it might not be adding `unsafe-eval`.