# How to use Vuetify in a chrome extension without build/bundler tools?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuetify.js

I'm creating a Chrome extension and want to use Vue.js and Vuetify for the popup UI.
The extension is using manifest version 3 (so, tighter CSP restrictions compared to v2).

I do not want to use any runtime/bundler/packer/transformer/build tool.

When including only the Vue library, I have no problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Only Vue</title>
    <script src="popup.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// popup.js
import {createApp, h} from "../vue.runtime.esm.browser.prod-3.3.9.js";
const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            message: "Hello vue!"
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addExclamation() {
            this.message += "!";
        }
    },
    render() {
        return h(
            "div",
            { onClick: () => { this.addExclamation(); } },
            this.message
        );
    }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

But, in the second version listed below, adding Vuetify,
the elements do not get styled (they won't even get compiled to `<div>`s). If I use a template string as in `const app = createApp({ template: "<v-app>...</v-app>" })`, it works when opened as a regular page in browser but the extension throws error complaining about the `eval` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Vue + Vuetify</title>
    <link href="../materialdesignicons-4.9.95-modified.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../vuetify-3.0.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../vue-3.3.9.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script src="../vuetify-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// popup.js
const {createApp} = Vue;
const {createVuetify} = Vuetify;
const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp({
    // ...
    render() {
        return h(
            "v-app",
            [h(
                "v-btn",
                "Click me"
            )]
        );
    }
});
app.use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```

Is it possible at all to use Vuetify without build tools in a Chrome extension?

Comment: You shouldn't use "v-app" string for vnode types, use the real component, same for v-btn. See https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>The popup</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- Make sure to use utf-8 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="../vuetify-3.4.4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="../vue.runtime.global-3.3.9.js"></script>
  <script src="../vuetify-3.4.4.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// popup.js

const {createApp, h} = Vue;
const {createVuetify} = Vuetify;
const {VApp, VCard, VCardText} = Vuetify.components;
const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            message: "Hello vue!"
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addExclamation() {
            this.message += "!";
        }
    },
    render() {
        return h(
            VApp,
            { onClick: () => this.addExclamation() },
            [
              h(
                VCard,
                {
                  class: "mx-auto",
                  width: "200",
                  "append-icon": "mdi-human-greeting"
                },
                [
                  h(
                    VCardText,
                    this.message
                  )
                ]
              )
            ]
        );
    }
});
app.use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```